# if of-hook agents in freeswitch can confirm incoming call from queue?

Tags: freeswitch

in default configuration in freeswitch, when a call falls into the queue and is routed to an agent, he immediately answers, I want to change that ...

so is there a way (is this possible) for off-hook agents (always connected agents) to acknowledge the call before bridge (for example by pressing DTMF code) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. In Freeswitch callcenter module (mod_callcenter.c), you can change it according to your need before bridge to agent. And you can write the code for sending dtmf to off-hook agents. I used to do the changes as per my requirement and I also wrote many custom specific modules.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I couldn't get any information about that even on the freeswitch live chat or mailing lists. Could you please put any part of the code how it should be done, or give more clues?

Comment: SWITCH_STANDARD_APP(callcenter_function). read this application written in mod_callcenter.still you are not able to do it you can contact at surendratiwari3@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve exporting group_confirm variables before executing the callcenter app.

```
-- first set the variables that you want to export
session:setVariable('group_confirm_file', 'file_string:///var/lib/freeswitch/confirm.wav')
session:setVariable('group_confirm_key', '1')
session:setVariable('confirm', 'true')

-- Exporting varibles, this variables the callcenter app will use and add to agents 
session:setVariable('cc_export_vars', 'group_confirm_file,group_confirm_key,confirm')

-- Then now execute the callcenter app
session:execute('callcenter', 'QUEUE-NAME-HERE')


Note: This example I used LUA, but it will be the same on XML
```